# Bluemix Build Error with Node 7

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud, devops-services

I have been building a react js application which is hosted within IBM Bluemix. I have recently had issues with my build stage as part of the CI/CD Pipeline - We believe the issue has been based around the Node version we were using when running the build phase - we are now using Node 7 and are currently recieveing following error based on the archive directory build/ (error message below) :

npm info it worked if it ends with ok

```
npm verb cli [ '/home/pipeline/nvm/versions/node/v7.0.0/bin/node',
npm verb cli   '/home/pipeline/nvm/versions/node/v7.0.0/bin/npm',
npm verb cli   'build',
npm verb cli   '--verbose' ]
npm info using npm@3.10.8
npm info using node@v7.0.0
npm verb exit [ 0, true ]
npm info ok
```

Archive directory build/ does not exist. Please check the name.

Finished: FAILED

Any advice or help with this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is usually thrown when you are defining a build directory that doesn't exist because it might not be getting created during your build job. In your pipeline build stage, can you check the "Build archive directory" field in the configuration and make sure the directory listed there exists? Also, you can try leaving the field blank. Let me know how it goes.